# SQL specific question - get child that belong to all item of a collection

Tags: sql, linq

The schema is here :

GROUP  1 ----> * USER 1 ----> 1 PERSON 1 ---> * ADRESSE 1 -----> 1 CITY

I would like to get only City that belong to **all Users**

is it possible natively with sql or do i need to do it iteratively.

To say in a simple way : i just want to have a list of city where each user of the group has a relation with ....

Don't focus on real life, in this model user can have thousand cities ...

i can try to draw it (maybe simpler)

```
GROUP 1 -----> USER 1 -> PERSON 1-> ADRESSE 1 -> CITY 1
        -----> USER 2 -> PERSON 2-> ADRESSE X -> CITY 1
        -----> USER 2 -> PERSON 2-> ADRESSE Y -> CITY 2
        -----> USER 3 -> PERSON 3-> ADRESSE Z -> CITY 1

I want only CITY 1
```

Comment: Can you please clarify? It looks like you want a City that `all` users have a link to but that doesn't make sense. Do you mean only cities that are linked to by at least one user?

Comment: no the example is bad, but imagine that users can have thousant city ( relation admit that) ... that i want is cities that have a relation with all the users but i don't want them if they have relation with only some users of the group ... the goal is linking cities by group, i've ask sql but Linq query would be good too (maybe easiyer)

Comment: By analogy, if you had a listing of every student in a school and all of their friends, you want to find the person (or persons) who is a friend to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this get you started?

```
Select cityname, count(distinct userID) 
from  User u inner join Person p on  u.personID = p.personID 
inner join Adresse a on  p.addressID = a.addressID
inner join City c on a.cityID = p.cityID 
group by cityName
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have ID fields in each table that tie them together... using this type of where clause will return only the rows that have a city...

`Select * 
from Group, User, Person, Adresse, City 
where city.cityID = addresse.cityID 
and addresse.addressID = person.adresse.addressID 
and person.personID = user.personID 
and user.userID = group.userID`